# Error running a 'npx tsc' command regarding Typescript: This is not the tsc command you are looking for

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, monorepo, npx

First to mention that TSC is deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc

This is the error I am getting:

> This is not the tsc command you are looking for

I am working on a monorepo so on 3 different `package.json` in the scripts key, I have something like this:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf lib/ && npx tsc && cp -R src/assets/ lib/assets/",
}
```

I would like to know how from my monorepo I can fix this problem and if I need to replace the `npx tsc` command with `npx typescript` command or something related to that?

Comment: Your script should call `tsc`, not `npx tsc`. (This will fail too if you haven’t installed TypeScript, but the correct fix is to install TypeScript.)

Comment: There are reasons not to install typescript. Neither to your package nor globally.

Comment: Please don't abandon your questions while continuing to ask new ones.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `npx` doesn't know where to find the right `tsc` command. It first looks for a package named `tsc`.

The warning is produced by a package named `tsc` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc). It used to do what we expected it to do. Now it is deprecated. It is not an official package by Microsoft. I hope the maintainer is not evil because the package has ~40.000 downloads/week.

The solution is to use the `-p` (or `--package`) switch to tell `npx` which package provides the `tsc` command. In this case it is the `typescript` package.

```
npx -p typescript tsc
```

So your script section should look like this

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf lib/ && npx -p typescript tsc && cp -R src/assets/ lib/assets/",
}
```

Comment: “first looks for a package named *tsc”? (Also, this is helpful for correct use of `npx`, but `npx` isn’t the correct way to use the TypeScript compiler from a package script.)

Answer (score 0):

`npx` will download a package from the registry and run it without having to install it. This is handy for small cli tools without having to add them into your dependencies.

`npx tsc` will install https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc and run it via [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) which is not what you're trying to do I gather. I think you'd like to run typescript.
For that you should install typescript into your project and run it via `npm run tsc` or just `tsc`.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf lib/ && npx tsc && cp -R src/assets/ lib/assets/",
}
```

To

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf lib/ && tsc && cp -R src/assets/ lib/assets/",
}
```

i.e. remove `npx`.